# SQL Query - derive a query which will find the average of numbers obtained by other queries

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have 5 different queries, in sql and i want to write a 6th query which will help me find the average of the 5 values i have derieved, how will that happen?

For example

Query 1 - gives me a number (2.6)
Query 2 - gives me a number (3.4)

And so on

$str1= (“select total from endpoints”)

$str2=(“select total from data”)

$str3 = (need an average of str1 and str2)

Help anyone?

Comment: Show these queries only description won't help you much

Comment: Do you need to do this with a query? Your `$str3` notation suggests that you could also resolve this in PHP: `$str3 = ($str1 + $str2)/2` (of course this is a simplified example)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `union all`:

```
select avg(val)
from (<query1> union all
      <query2> union all
      <query3> union all
      <query4> union all
      <query5> union all
     ) t;
```

`val` is assumed to be the name of the value that you want the average of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !
Simply take the average of two SELECT queries joining them using UNION ALL clause.

```
SELECT AVG ( 
                 SELECT total 
                 FROM   endpoints 
                UNION ALL 
                 SELECT total 
                 FROM   data
           )
```